# Unselect button inside macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an excel macro that takes a horribly formatted table and for the most part puts all the data in the correct place. So instead of retyping out the data manually which would take 8+ hours, it only takes ~30 minutes to check and make sure everything is correct.

At the very end of my macro I have created a button which allows for the final formatting to take place which will set up the workbook to become a comma deliminated file so that it can be imported to a database.

```
'The 4 arguments determine where the cells top left corner is and its width,height
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add( _
    ActiveSheet.Columns(7).Left, _
    ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Top, _
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Width * 2, _
    ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Height * 2).Select

'creates all the settings for the button
Selection.Name = "btnFormat"
Selection.OnAction = "Final_Formatting"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("New Button").Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "Complete Formatting"
```

The problem is, that at the very end the button is still selected, and I'd like to unselect it. I've searched elsewhere and most people say to just select something else, but I simply want to unselect the button, nothing else. Is this possible?

Also, if anyone has suggestions on how to clean up the 4 arguments please feel free to comment. I got that portion off of the internet and adapted it to my own purposes but it looks ridiculous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'clean up the 4 arguments'- could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: In short, I'd like to reduce the number of lines used, possibly by combining the left/top and width/height properties.

Comment: To be honest I like the way you do it at the moment. If you need you could put there just figures like `ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(120, 30, 60, 20)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your button to be selected simply don't select it (as you do currently). I propose some improvements in the code below:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim btn As Button
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add( _
    ActiveSheet.Columns(7).Left, _
    ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Top, _
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Width * 2, _
    ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Height * 2)
'there is no selection method above!

'creates all the settings for the button
With btn
    .Name = "btnFormat"
    .OnAction = "Final_Formatting"
    'ActiveSheet.Shapes("btnFormat").Select- this line is not needed
    .Characters.Text = "Complete Formatting"
End With

End Sub
```

As a result cells range will be selected after the code run.

Comment: I tried it out, worked fine, although everything else on the sheet we selected, but I feel this is due to the previous portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as there has always to be a selected element, I think that "unselect" option cannot exist (because might provoke cases where no element is selected). The usual proceeding is just selecting other thing. In this case, I guess that selecting any cell would work for you:

```
Range("A1").Select
```

Regarding the creation of the button, first of all, this code is wrong (and is actually triggering an error on my computer). If you want to use `Select` you have to remove the `Set btn =` part. Other than that, you have to pass these arguments but can remove the ActiveSheet part as far as it is implicit (it is recommendable to rely on the actual names of the worksheets; but if the situation is "under control" you can rely on ActiveSheet).

```
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Columns(7).Left, Rows(2).Top, Columns(1).Width * 2, Rows(1).Height * 2)

ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Columns(7).Left, Rows(2).Top, Columns(1).Width * 2, Rows(1).Height * 2).Select
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized after implementing the other answer that I had accidentally left the "Set btn =" in there after I had deleted the btn variable. It ran perfectly fine on my computer for some reason

Thanks for the advice on cleaning up the location and size of the button though, that definitely make it a lot neater.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to do that unfortunately.

Comment: Ah... No problem. To be honest, the reason why I said that was because the minimum length of the comment is 15 characters and I had to write something else than "You are welcome" LOL